# How to convert a Django ListView to work on the admin site?

Tags: python, django

I have a list view (for the admin site) that uses a template as follows:

```
class UserImageListPendingView(ListView):
    model = UserImage
    queryset = UserImage.objects.filter(status=ImageBase.PENDING)
    template_name = 'userimage_list_pending.html'
    context_object_name = 'userimage_list'
    paginate_by = 5
    @method_decorator(staff_member_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(UserImageListPendingView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Although this works there are problems with putting the URL in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/app/pendinguserimages/?$', login_required(
        UserImageListPendingView.as_view()),
        name='pendinguserimages'),
...
]
```

...as this stops the redirection working properly.

I did try to define the URL through admin.py:

```
def get_admin_urls(urls):
    def get_urls():
        return patterns('',
            url(r'^app/pendinguserimages/?$',
                 UserImageListPendingView.as_view(), name='pendinguserimages'),
        url(r'^app/checkuserimage/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/?$',
            userimage_check, name='checkuserimage'),
            ...
        ) + urls
    return get_urls

admin_urls = get_admin_urls(admin.site.get_urls())
admin.site.get_urls = admin_urls
```

... but there was an error when reversing the checkuserimage URL.

How would I go about converting this view to fit in better with the admin site, but still use the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need to rewrite the ListView afterall.  After defining the URLs in admin.py instead of in urls.py, all I needed to do was put "admin:" in front of the name when reversing the URL in the template, as follows:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:checkuserimage' record.id %}">check</a>
```